# Updating fields display names in Schema.xml of list definition is not working

Tags: list-definition, sharepoint-fields

I have created a list and deployed it to the SharePoint site. (It is SharePoint 2010 on-premise, but I think the process is same the for 2010 and 2013)

Later on client wanted to change the display name of couple of columns/fields. So, I made changes in those columns'/fields' display names (and in descriptions of those columns) in *Schema.xml* and updated wsp on that site (`Update-SPSoltion`).

I found that in *NewForm.aspx* the fields didn't change their display names. It shows the old names on new item form but it did change the descriptions of those fields.

Am I missing something? 
Why wouldn't the display names of fields change but descriptions do just fine?

Can anybody point in the right direction?

Thanks!

**Update:** When I check in List settings, I can clearly see that the display names are changed in the columns section. But the NewForm and EditForm show the old names.

Comment: Were these forms edited/customized at some points?

Comment: No. The modifications that are done to the list definition are by WSP update only.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this for those columns in `<Field` inside Schema.xml

```
ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
ShowInNewForm="TRUE"
```

Note: Type "TRUE" or "True" but not "true"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this one also didn't work.